# How to click an image in a web page with selenium

Tags: python, image, selenium, click

I am trying to click a button on the page ( https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm ) .

Background: I am not regular selenium user. Just trying to get some data from a website. Got to know about selenium from some help pages.

Some how i am not being able to click the "**Get Data**" button .

Here is my progress for the rest of the things which *works fine*.

```
url="https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"

options = Options()
options.headless = False

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

select=Select(browser.find_element_by_id('dataType'))
select.select_by_value("priceVolumeDeliverable")

select=Select(browser.find_element_by_id('series'))
select.select_by_value("EQ")
#time.sleep(5)

select=browser.find_element_by_id('symbol')
select.clear()
select.send_keys("RELIANCE")

select=Select(browser.find_element_by_id('dateRange'))
select.select_by_value("3month")
```

I have tried the following to click "**Get Data**" .

```
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitMe"]')
submit_button.click()

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.getdata-button').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='submitMe']").click();
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img/@src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_id("get").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("submitMe").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='getdata-button']//div[@id='get']").click()

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('//*[@id="get"]').click()

browser.find_element_by_id("#get")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="button" and @value="Get Results"]'))
```

Any suggestions friends ?

Comment: Do you logging enabled? If so what is logged when it comes to clicking the desired button(Get Data)?

Comment: I tried with driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='submitMe']/preceding-sibling::img").click(); and it works fine.

Comment: Site freezes on manually click in browser opened by webdriver. Do you have to use Selenium?

Comment: @sers Selenium came to mind as a first choice as it was easy and widely used. You have any other suggestions ?

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera i will try your solution. thx.

Comment: @harindersingh logging is enabled. as was trying very hard to get it working i failed to notice any meaningful error message which can help to debug further. thx

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera somehow  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='submitMe']/preceding-sibling::img").click();  freezes the browser on my CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) ,  chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) . Could you post your complete test code as  solution so that i can find my mistake. thx

Comment: @pksneo if you not tied to Selenium, I can give you another solution to get data

Comment: @sers thanks. But how do i input values to text fields, select values from drop-downs, select the radio buttons and above all i need to do it in python !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data using [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) and [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). You can play with `params` to get data you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm',
}

params = (
    ('symbol', 'RELIANCE'),
    ('segmentLink', '3'),
    ('symbolCount', '2'),
    ('series', 'EQ'),
    ('dateRange', '3month'),
    ('fromDate', ''),
    ('toDate', ''),
    ('dataType', 'PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE'),
)

response = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp',
                        headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.select("tr")

for th in soup.select("th"):
    print(th.text)

for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    table_data = rows[i].select("td")
    for td in table_data:
        print(td.text)
```

Comment: thats amazing. just saw your solution. I will try it quickly and update.

Comment: @ sers this is working. and a more reliable solution then selenium. thanks